# custom elements and class decorators

Tags: typescript, custom-element

custom elements act differently on class decorators?

Example:

index.html

```
<test-2></test-2>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
```

test2.ts => test2.js (target:es2017)

```
function defineClass(tagname: string) {
  return function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    console.log("Define: " + constructor.name)
    window.customElements.define(tagname, constructor)
    return class extends constructor {
        newProperty = "decorator";
        hello = "decorator";
    }
  }
}

@defineClass('test-2')
class Greeter2 extends HTMLElement{
  property = 'property2'
  hello = 'hello2'
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log(this.hello)
  }
  connectedCallback() { }
  disconnectedCallback() { }
  attributeChangedCallback(name: string, oldValue: string, newValue: string) { }
  adoptedCallback() { }
}
console.log('test-2: ', document.querySelector('test-2').hello)

@defineClass('test-3')
class Greeter3 {
  property = 'property3'
  hello = 'hello3'
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.hello)
  }
}
console.log('test-3: ', new Greeter3());
```

Output:

```
Define: Greeter2
hello2
test-2:  hello2 <= expected "decorator" like Greeter3 does

Define: Greeter3
hello3
test-3: Object {property: "property3", hello: "decorator", newProperty: "decorator"}
```

Is this the way it's suppose to be working? If so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to https://github.com/rictic for finding the solution, asked if he had time to answer it on stack, but don't think he has account so I paste it instead.

```
function defineClass(tagname: string) {
  return function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    console.log("Define: " + constructor.name)
    const generated = class extends constructor {
        newProperty = "decorator";
        hello = "decorator";
    }
    window.customElements.define(tagname, generated)
    return generated;
  }
}
```